# What do Rituals of Blood and Night (orc magic) tax?

Tags: spells, magic, rituals, burning-wheel, orc

In Burning Wheel Gold pages 244-246 it is described how Orc magic (Rituals of Blood and Night) work. Orc mages (Servants) have either the Rituals of Blood skill or the Rituals of Night skill and Sorcery-like spells. Additionally their Hatred is replaced by Void Embrace emotional attribute. On page 244 it states that this attribute is used to resist the tax caused by the Rituals of Blood/Night and that the tax can't be resisted without it.

### Question:

What attribute is taxed during this process?
Is it

1. Forte just like with human sorcery?
2. Void Embrace itself analogously with sorcery (test Forte or tax Forte) and Resources (fail Resources test and tax Resources)?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rituals of Blood and Night are like Sorcery with the exception that [Void Embrace is rolled to resist Tax to Forte instead of Forte being used to resist Tax to Forte](https://www.burningwheel.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-14336.html). The remaining Tax rules on 504 are still in play, including unconsciousness at Forte 0 and wound penalties for Overtax.

Comment: Thor's answer also mentions “recovery”, but that use of Void Embrace is not mentioned anywhere else in BWG, so I suspect he meant “resist”.